# error in creating mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, orbeon

I get an error when i execute this script:

```
create table orbeon_form_definition_attach (
created            timestamp(6),
last_modified_time timestamp(6),
last_modified_by   varchar(255)           CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
app                varchar(255)           CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
form               varchar(255)           CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
form_version       int not null,
deleted            char(1)                                   COLLATE utf8_bin        NOT     NULL,
file_name          varchar(255)           CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
file_content       longblob
)   engine = InnoDB;
```

The error is : **Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual** **that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near (6),**     **last_modified_time timestamp(6),     last_modified_by   varchar(255)  at line 2    0.000 sec**

any idea how to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime` or `timestamp` does not have a length

```
create table orbeon_form_definition_attach 
(
created            datetime,
last_modified_time datetime,
last_modified_by   varchar(255)           CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
app                varchar(255)           CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
form               varchar(255)           CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
form_version       int not null,
deleted            char(1)                                   COLLATE utf8_bin        NOT     NULL,
file_name          varchar(255)           CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
file_content       longblob
)   engine = InnoDB;
```

Comment: As of MySQL 5.6.4 `time`, `datetime` or `timestamp` can have a length, see [MySQL manual, fractional seconds in time values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)